# Adblock Plus filter to block youtube 'Popular feed videos ' on homepage?

Tags: youtube, adblock, web-filtering

I don't like the Youtube's popular feed videos on front page, few of them have adult stuff or NSFW thumbnails which i don't like. its a distraction.

I added a custom filter i.e. main-feed-content' but it also blocked my watch later videos and subscriptions. So, does anyone know the solution?

[image]

Here are the filters which i added to remove Junk from twitter and facebook.
Bottom 2 removes trending topics and footer from twitter.
third and forth removes sidebars from facebook.

Second removed popular feed but it also removes the stuff which i have already mentioned.

[image]